# Increment month column by 1 and store in scala variable

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a table of weather history data month wise.

```
Bangalore   27      65          2021-04
Chennai     30      85          2021-04
Mumbai      31      84          2021-04
Bangalore   27      65          2021-05
Chennai     30      85          2021-05
Mumbai      31      84          2021-05
Bangalore   26      62          2021-06
Chennai     31      88          2021-06
Mumbai      32      89          2021-06
```

Im using Databricks...I want to check to see which month data has been uploaded recently. (2021-06 in the above case)

The reason for doing so is so that i can increment the yearmonth and ingest the next month's data. (Example: 2021-06 should be incremented as 2021-07)

Im going to use this paramater yearmonth in my below scala code, and will be later used for ingestion of data.

```
%scala
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val sourceID = dbutils.widgets.get("sourceID")
val split_val = sourceID.split(",")
val sourceIDs = split_val(0)
val measure = split_val(1)
val yearmonth = spark.sql(""" SELECT MAX(snapshot_month) FROM curated_ga.f_clm_segments_raw """)

sql(s"set acquisition_channel = $acquisition_channel")
sql(s"set sourceIDs = $sourceIDs")
sql(s"set measure = $measure")
sql(s"set yearmonth = $yearmonth")
```

and get output as:

```
sourceID: String = 156,ppg
split_val: Array[String] = Array(156, ppg)
sourceIDs: String = 156
measure: String = ppg
yearmonth: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [max(snapshot_month): string]
acquisition_channel: String = acquisition_channel in ('01','02')
res25: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, value: string]
```

Is there anyway i can get the latest month, increment it by 1 so it refers to next month...and store that value as yearmonth.
Example 2021-06 should be incremented to 2021-07 and stored to yearmonth.

Comment: What do you mean by "store that value as yearmonth"? Do you add a 'yearmonth' column in the dataset? or you want a local scala variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use date functions in Scala to work with your column and increment it.  In this example I've used `to_date`, `add_months` and `date_format` to achieve the result:

### Cell 1

```
// Assign sample data to dataframe
val df = Seq(
    ( "example1", "1999-12" ),
    ( "example2", "2000-02" ),
    ( "example3", "2000-10" )
    ).
    toDF("country", "yearmonth")
```

### Cell 2

```
val df2 = df.
    withColumn("yearMonthToDate", to_date($"yearmonth")).
    withColumn("working1", expr("add_months(yearMonthToDate, 1)")).
    withColumn("working2", date_format($"working1", "yyyy-MM")).
    withColumn("allTogether", date_format(add_months(to_date($"yearmonth"),1), "yyyy-MM"))

df2.show
```

My results:

[image: Results]

NB The same functions are available in Spark SQL:

```
SELECT *, date_format(add_months(to_date(yearmonth),1),'yyyy-MM') x
FROM tmp
```

I cannot quite follow your code but the best way to get an answer to this type of question is to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as I have with just three records, one which shows the year changing, and two others which just show the month incrementing, rather than your whole prod code.

Comment: Any update on this?